# How to make gridview scrollable horizantally and vertically?

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview inside a div as follows:

```
<div id="divPopUpFiles" runat="server" style="background-color: White; width: 800px;
        height: 410px; position: absolute; border-color: Black; border-style: groove;
        border-width: thin; display: none; z-index: 10001;">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="PopUpPanel" runat="server" Visible="false" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOk"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblModifiedFilesMessage" runat="server" />
    <asp:GridView ID="gvPopUpModifiedFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CssClass="dataTable" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" style="overflow: auto; width: 800px; max-height: 200px;">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFileSelect" runat="server" Checked="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FileName" DataField="FileName" />
                </Columns>
                     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
      </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOk" Text="OK" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" onclick="btnOk_Click" /><br />
      </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
```

I used the overflow:auto still I am unable to make my grid scrollable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code.

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 800px; max-height: 200px;">
<asp:GridView ID="gvPopUpModifiedFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CssClass="dataTable" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" style="overflow: auto; width: 800px; max-height: 200px;">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkFileSelect" runat="server" Checked="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FileName" DataField="FileName" />
                </Columns>
                     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
      </asp:GridView>
</div>
```